# Expose Android and iOS native code SDK to Javascript in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2

I actually found a third party plugin that I want to use on one of my project. The goal is to create an Ionic application for that to avoid wasting time coding in native for both Android and iOS.

The problem is that the plugin I found has only SDK for Android and iOS. After a discussion on their forum, a technical guy told me it was possible for me to use that on Ionic by creating a plugin to expose the code to the Javascript.

Do you know where I could start ?
Do you have any tips or advice on how I could do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I actually found a third party plugin that I want to use on one of my project.

By plugin I understand you mean a *Cordova* plugin. A link would be nice.

> a technical guy told me it was possible for me to use that on Ionic by creating a plugin to expose the code to the Javascript.

By creating a plugin to expose the code (of the Cordova plugin?) to javascript, I understand you want to make an Ionic wrapper for that Cordova plugin.

If so, first check that your plugin doesn't already have a Cordova wrapper in the list of those over at [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

If not, then you can have a look at how all the [other wrappers are already written](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/tree/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins) and get started from there.

If you actually want to create your own cordova plugin, then here's [a great tutorial](https://medium.com/ionic-and-the-mobile-web/how-to-write-cordova-plugins-864e40025f2) by Ionic's CEO to help you out.